# LLVM IR getelementptr LLVM C API equivalent

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to write an LLVM C API code to generate an LLVM assembly code to count the number of characters in a string.  I need to know how to write a    getelementptr in LLVM IR equivalent in LLVM C API.  I've looked all over google and can't seem to find an answer.  Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `LLVMBuildGEP` function from the C API. You can see its prototype in `include/llvm-c/Core.h`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for - I didn't realize GEP was GetElementPtr.

Comment: @EliBendersky Hi, the LLVMBuildGEP is implemented as `wrap(unwrap(B)->CreateGEP(nullptr, unwrap(Pointer), IdxList, Name));`.  Does it mean that if using LLVM C API, we can only pass nullptr to the first argument of  `CreateGEP`?

Comment: @EliBendersky I try to implement a function using pure C (with LLVM C API). The function's only parameter is a pointer to `<2 x i32>*`, it returns the second element in the vector.  The LLVM IR should be `getelementptr i32, <2 x i32>* %0, i32 1`. I fail to generate the code using `LLVMBuildGEP`.   Would you give some tips?  Thanks so much.